# Where has "Message text garbled?" gone in gmail?

Tags: email, gmail

I want to see the text version of email in gmail. How can i check please some one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail removed “Message text garbled?” option now you can see text version of your email using following steps.

1. From the "More" menu, select "Show original"
2. In the address bar, update the "view" parameter in the query string from "om" to "dom"

Comment: this doesn't seem to work any more